# Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action : JSF

Tags: jsf, navigation

I am getting the following error : 
Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action '#{medcontroller.getMedGeneric}' with outcome 'javax.faces.model.ListDataModel@7a652236'

I am new to jsf and I'm really clueless about solving this error. I have a ManagedBean with the following code:

MedController.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "medcontroller")
@SessionScoped

public class MedController implements Serializable {
    int startId;
    String gName;
    int endId;
    DataModel medNames;
    //DataModel medGeneric;
    MedicineHelper helper;
    private int recordCount = 1000;
    private int pageSize = 10;
    private Medicine current;
    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public MedController() {
        helper = new MedicineHelper();
        startId = 1;
        endId = 10;
    }

    public MedController(int startId, int endId) {
        helper = new MedicineHelper();
        this.startId = startId;
        this.endId = endId;
    }

    public Medicine getSelected() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new Medicine();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    public DataModel getMedNames() {
        if (medNames == null) {
            medNames = new ListDataModel(helper.getMedNames(startId, endId));
        }
        return medNames;
    }

    public String getgName()
        {
        return gName;
    }

    public void setgName(String gName)
        {
        this.gName = gName;
    }

    public DataModel getMedGeneric() {
        if (medNames == null) {
            medNames= new ListDataModel(helper.getMedGeneric(gName));
        }
        return medNames;
    }

    void recreateModel() {
        medNames = null;
    }

    public boolean isHasNextPage() {
        if (endId + pageSize <= recordCount) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isHasPreviousPage() {
        if (startId-pageSize > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String next() {
        startId = endId+1;
        endId = endId + pageSize;
        recreateModel();
        return "index";
    }

    public String previous() {
        startId = startId - pageSize;
        endId = endId - pageSize;
        recreateModel();
        return "index";
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

   public String prepareView(){
        current = (Medicine) getMedNames().getRowData();
        return "browse";
    }
   public String prepareList(){
        recreateModel();
        return "index";
    }

}
```

And here is my JSF file

index.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
    <h:commandLink action="#{medcontroller.previous}" value="Previous #{medcontroller.pageSize}" rendered="#{medcontroller.hasPreviousPage}"/> 
    <h:commandLink action="#{medcontroller.next}" value="Next #{medcontroller.pageSize}" rendered="#{medcontroller.hasNextPage}"/> 
    <h:dataTable value="#{medcontroller.medNames}" var="item" border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="10" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="BrandName"/>
        </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.brandName}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Generic"/>
        </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.generic}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value=" "/>
        </f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{medcontroller.prepareView}" value="View"/>
    </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:inputText value="#{medcontroller.gName}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{medcontroller.getMedGeneric}" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Please help me solve the error.
Also, I do not have a faces-config.xml file. I am using netbeans ide 7.1.2 web application with jsf and hibernate framework.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You forgot to tell what exactly you want to happen when you press that "submit" button.

Comment: Careful with `get` prefix. It is very generic for getters only. You don't "get" something from a database, if it is not a backing bean properry. JSF can maybe see that otherwise. Better use `fetchMedGeneric()`, including the braces.

Comment: And also, if you have an error, please always include the complete back-trace.

Comment: And you use `@ManagedBean` which is deprecated JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<h:commandButton action>` must point to a method which invokes some business logic and returns either `void` or a `String` representing the target page you'd like to (re)display. However you returned a whole `ListDataModel` which isn't making any sense to JSF navigation handler and hence this error.

Something like this should do:

```
public String getMedGeneric(){ 
    // Do your business logic here.

    return "someViewId";
}
```

This will navigate to `someViewId.xhtml`. However, if you intend to stick on the same view, just let it return `void` (or `null`) and it will redisplay the same view.

```
public void getMedGeneric(){ 
    // Do your business logic here.
}
```

By the way, it's really a poor naming convention to prefix action method names with `get`. This is confusing and makes your code not self-documenting. Rather name it `loadMedGeneric()` or so. I'm merely guessing as you didn't tell anywhere about the concrete functional requirement, what exactly that button should be doing.

Comment: If I add `?faces-redirect=true` to the returned outcome of my backing bean method, I get the message with the `?faces-redirect=true` added. It seem not to work!

Comment: <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/admin/branch_office/admin_branch_office_edit.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>admin_list_branch_office</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/admin/branch_office/admin_branch_office_list.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>

Comment: Then you're not using JSF 2.x but the jurassic JSF 1.x.

Comment: The `faces-config.xml` with its `navigation-rule` is outdated? How can I make sure that the navigation is secure? Adding an empty `<redirect></redirect>` has fixed my issue here.

Comment: I found the `get` prefix ambicious as `get` is for getters, like `<h:inputText value="#{someBean.foo}" />` and then you have `private Foo foo;` with `public Foo getFoo()` and `public void setFoo(final Foo foo)`. Yes, `final` for parameters, optional but recommended.

Answer (score 0):

getMedGeneric should return java.lang.String which represent navigation to another page described in faces-config.xml. In your case it return some model so it will not work unfortunatell. Let try to put getMedGeneric() action to actionListener and then in action put navigation String. i.e:

```
action="navString" actionListener="#{medcontroller.getMedGeneric}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not working, still shows an error :Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action 'navString' with outcome 'navString'

Answer (score -2):

you should try just

```
actionListener="#{medcontroller.getMedGeneric}"
```